# Odd numbers of object extraction from an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to get 2 objects at a time form the array for now. but soon I will be using odd number of length and splicing items.

This works out perfectly so far with Even numbers in the Array, but I am not sure how to make it work with odd numbers. The way I think it may work is ask it to check the objects coming up next and if it is less than 2 than change the counters to 1. but I am not even sure how to put that in code specifically. I posted my code so far be

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.Socket;


var socket_Array_current_position = 0;
var socket_counter = 2;
var socket_Array: Array = new Array ();

socket_Array.push(socket_one, socket_two,socket_three, socket_four, socket_five, socket_six);



go_next_left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_left);
go_next_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_right);

function go_left(going_left:MouseEvent)
{

    if (socket_Array_current_position > 0)
    {
        socket_remove();
        socket_Array_current_position -=  socket_counter;
        socket_x_position = 125;
        socket_display();
    }

}

function go_right(going_right:MouseEvent)
{
    if (socket_Array_current_position < socket_Array.length-socket_counter)
    {
    socket_remove();
    socket_Array_current_position +=  socket_counter;
    socket_x_position = 125;
    socket_display();
    }
}



socket_display();

function socket_display()
{
    var s = 0;
    for (s; s < socket_counter; s++)
    {
        addChild(socket_Array[socket_Array_current_position + s]);
        socket_Array[socket_Array_current_position + s].x = socket_x_position;
        socket_Array[socket_Array_current_position + s].y = socket_y_position;
        //socket_Array[s].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, picked);
        socket_x_position = socket_x_position + 275;
    }
}


function socket_remove()
{
    var s = 0;
    for (s; s < socket_counter; s++)
    {

        removeChild(socket_Array[socket_Array_current_position+s]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal example. I don't understand your question, and that's too much code for me to dig through!

Comment: yep i will do that right away sorry about that

Comment: I did that, can u please look over it again :D

Comment: I still don't really understand. If you had items [a,b,c,d,e], what would you expect to get out? [a,b], [b,c], [c,d], [d,e]? Or [a,b], [c,d]? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want display X objects (in this case two) at a time from an array. Whatever length. I'm using Math lib. Consider that I didn't try the code below with sdk or Flash.

```
const X_START_POS:int = 125;
const COLUMN_WIDTH:int = 275;
const QTY_SCREEN:int = 2;  
var socket_Array:Array = new Array(); 
var socket_Array_pos:int = 0; 
var socket_Array_target:int = 0; // target is always right 
var socket_Array_on_screen:Array = new Array();

// socket_Array.length must be >= QTY_SCREEN, always.
socket_Array.push(socket_one, socket_two, socket_three, socket_four, socket_five, socket_six); 

go_next_left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_left);
go_next_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_right);

socket_display();

function go_left(going_left:MouseEvent) {
    socket_Array_target = Math.max(socket_Array_pos - QTY_SCREEN, 0);
    socket_display();
}

function go_right(going_right:MouseEvent) {
    socket_Array_target = Math.min(socket_Array_pos + QTY_SCREEN, socket_Array.length - QTY_SCREEN);
    socket_display();
}

function socket_display() {
    socket_remove();
    socket_x_position = X_START_POS;
    var limit:int = socket_Array_target + QTY_SCREEN;
    for (var i = socket_Array_target; i < limit; i++) {
        show_socket(socket_Array[i]);
        socket_x_position += COLUMN_WIDTH; 
    }
    socket_Array_pos = socket_Array_target;
}

function show_socket(asocket:DisplayObject) {
   addChild(asocket);
   asocket.x = socket_x_position;
   asocket.y = socket_y_position;
   socket_Array_on_screen.push(asocket);  // remember me
}

function socket_remove() {
    var qty:int = socket_Array_on_screen.length;
    for (var s = 0; s < qty; s++) {
        removeChild(socket_Array_on_screen.pop());
    }
}
```